# How to automatically shutdown below certain battery level

Tags: battery

Is there a way to make my phone turn off when the battery level is below 50%?

At the moment it does this when the battery level (or voltage) is critically low, but I want it to do it when there is still half the juice left.

A paid app would be fine too.

Comment: I think I could write you one, but from what I can find online you will have to root your device to allow the app to shut down your device. I could write one that gives a notification which means you won't need to root.

Comment: Rooting the subduct l device is inevitable for full automation and control over the device.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of paying for Tasker, the same things can be automated for free using the app [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate). It has [blocks](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/index.html) for checking battery level and rebooting the device. However, rebooting a device programmatically will required a rooted device.

Comment: (NOT TESTED) There is a community flow for shutting down below 10% battery: https://llamalab.com/automate/community/flows/31775

Answer (score 2):

In Android, In order to shutdown or to reboot a device, programatically, based on certain system parameters (such as battery level), Phone needs to be **ROOTED**.

So, any apps that wants to achieve the functionality that you mentioned, can only Work on ROOTED Devices.

The closet app which offers Shutdown that I came across is "Shutdown Timer" by SpecSoft.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.specsoft.shutdowntimertrial

Please note that this app does *not* shutdown phone when battery is low (which is what you asked), but allow user to "Schedule" shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the app `Tasker`.
With Tasker you are able to literally *automate* your whole phone.
There are also many tutorials covering the of Tasker and what you can do with it (change settings and launch apps based on events, location, time and other variables)

> As with many similar applications, this one needs root for many functions.