# I have an unrooted stock Xperia Z Ultra, should the LED turn off when the battery is fully charged?

Tags: charging, 5.1-lollipop, sony-xperia, stock-rom

I got an Xperia Z Ultra unrooted and still running on the stock ROM (Android Lollipop 5.1.1). My question is, when I'm charging it and the battery reaches 100%, is the LED indicator light supposed to turn off to notify that it's fully charged? So I'm kinda asking what behavior I should expect from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[User guide](http://support.sonymobile.com/global-en/xperiazultra/userguide/Charging-your-device/) doesn't say it should be switched off on full. Expected behaviour below

> Battery notification light status
>
> *Green*   The battery is charging and the battery charge level is greater than 90%
>
> *Red*     The battery is charging and the battery charge level is less than 15%
>
> *Orange*  The battery is charging and the battery charge level is less than 90%

Edit: If the LED turned off, you wouldn't know whether it is fully charged or charger isn't connected, color coding this way makes sense

Comment: What is the convention for other Xperia phones? Is it safe to leave it plugged in without worrying it will overcharge the battery?

Comment: For any Android phone, keeping it charged overnight is not advisable, as it tends to keep the battery at high temperatures, adversely affecting battery life. They don't overcharge as modern chargers take care of that

Comment: You will find plenty of articles on the net saying it is safe to charge overnight but for best charging range, see this http://android.stackexchange.com/a/156538/131553

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help. Didn't understand *both of you* :)

Comment: Derp, I thought the other person who commented was a different person