# What is the best state to leave an Android device in?

Tags: charging, battery-life, maintenance

I have a Moto E phone. I use it as a tablet to run apps, not as a phone, so I do not always need to leave it on.

Is it more likely that the device will last longer if I shut it off whenever I am not using it? Or is it better for the hardware of a phone to leave it constantly on, in sleep mode?

And is it better to leave it constantly charging, or to only charge it whenever the battery is below 100%?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at it from a battery point of view

- Leaving the device in *sleep* mode is preferred , unless your usage is very infrequent
- In addition, you can use *Greenify* (see [greenify](/questions/tagged/greenify) wiki) and Wake Lock Detector as explained [here for unrooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/146399/131553)
- As far as ideal charging limits are concerned, you can see this and decide what suits you best [Ideal charging / discharging percentage for maximum battery life?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/156526/131553)
- Also see [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1020/131553)
- Switcing off Wi-Fi and Bluetooth

Once your battery consumption is taken care off,  there isn't any concern in leaving it switched on in sleep mode

Answer (score 1):

"Should I shut off my phone when not using it?"

You must keep in mind that starting a phone consumes a lot of battery. So, you shouldn't shut down your phone if you are going to use it again in 15 to 20 minutes. Otherwise, it is a good idea to shut off your phone to save battery. But will it increase your phone's life? The answer is **No**.

"Better to leave it constantly charging?"

Overcharging won't have any bad effect on your phone. But if you really wanna increase your phone's battery life, always keep the battery percentage between 10% and 90%. It wil increase the longevity of your phone's battery by a lot.

Comment: I think it is from 40 to 90℅.

Comment: No @MANI, I am completely sure about the numbers.

Comment: Perhaps @MANI was talking of [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/156526/131553) while quoting ideal range. Please support your figures with sources to back up, since you are *completely sure about the numbers*. Thanks