# Keeping phone plugged in vs. using a charger control?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, overheating

I have an old, quite banged-up Huawei Y6II. I want to use it as a static device and turn it into a security camera, web server, wifi hotspot, etc. Is it okay to keep it plugged in all the time? Or should I use a DIY solution that controls the charging cable with a relay in a way that the cable is turned on when the battery is low and then turned off when it is full?

To clarify, I am not asking about the DIY solution, I have a plan for that already. My question is, is it worth going into the hassle, or is it just fine to normally keep the phone plugged in 24x7?

Please note, there are frequent power outages here.

And in case this info is useful - the battery of the phone was replaced once and the new battery was purchased from a "*don't know how trustworthy*" shop, but it works okay, and the price was close to an original replacement.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how long (years) you want you use your old phone in that role //If it's for a couple of years (assuming replacement battery is good) it's fine //If you are thinking of longer terms than definitely it's good to restrict as you intended. [See this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/156538/131553)

Comment: If a device is plugged in 24/7 the battery of some devices start to blow up, so that even the device case gets opened or breaks. If your device can be rooted I would recommend to do so, then most devices allow to enable/disable charging programmatically even is USB connection provides power all the time.