# My android phone drains from 100 percent to 0 percent in 20 minutes

Tags: battery

I have been using my laptop to charge my android phone until recently when I noticed the back lid pushed to the back slightly and then the battery drains from 100 percent to 0 percent in 20 minutes. I suspect either the charging system or the battery. How can I be sure of the problem so I don't replace the battery to find out its a charging system issue?

Comment: I haven't understood the problem description. Anyway, does this happen when charged from the OEM power brick also?

Comment: yeah it also happens when charged from a regular charger

Comment: In that case it's  most likely a battery issue. Likely your device is more than 3 years old or heavily used. In any case, you are left with the option of changing the battery

Comment: Yes i bought it back in 2019 and that explains why the battery should be the problem,  thanks i just hope a new battery won't get drained so fast

Comment: As someone who has replaced Nexus 5's battery 3 times, there are at least 2 factors: The first is one is obviously these batteries have broken (swollen), but they also broke fast due to being incorrectly charged (continuously overnight, overcharged, ungrounded outlet, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Andrew T., that is exactly what I used to do, my phone would spend the night plugged in to my laptop, didn't know that was detrimental to the health of the battery

Comment: The more often you charge a battery sit it is already close to 100% the faster the battery dies. Especially keeping it connected means it will charge to 100 and then stop charging. As most phones can not directly use the USB power it will discharge until about 95% is reached. So this is the fastest way to kill a battery.

Comment: @CoderTimothy please see this https://android.stackexchange.com/q/156526/131553